# .load() page and preload all content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replicate jQuery Mobile's page navigation system wherein you can call a page which is loaded into the dom in a container floated to the right and then animated over and have the following so far: http://s46264.gridserver.com/dev/dave/pageslider/

My problem is that i'd like to preload all page contents before calling the animate statement (see load page 2) How can I do this?

Code so far:

```
var currPage = "one";

        function loadPage(newPage) {
            $("<div id='" + newPage + "' class='page'></div>").insertAfter('#'+currPage);
            $('#'+newPage).load('pages/' + newPage + '.php', function() {       
                $('#page_wrapper').animate({
                    left: '-400px'
                }, 200, function() {
                    $('#'+currPage).remove();
                    $('#page_wrapper').css('left',0);
                    currPage = newPage;
                });
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#page_wrapper").append("<div id='" + currPage + "' class='page'></div>");
            $('#'+currPage).load('pages/' + currPage + '.php');
        })
```

Also, i'm quite new so any tips on errors in my approach are well received.

Thanks

Comment: doesn't the script you have do what you are asking for?

Comment: In his example the image on page 2 only loads until the div slides in. He wants to find out if he can preload this content so the image is already there when the page slides in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following solution:

http://chipsandtv.com/articles/jquery-image-preload

Have you tried going over all image tags in the DOM that you have preloaded and create image elements in memory with the following:

```
// images is an array with the image filenames, so you'd 
// have to extract these from the preloaded source.
$(images).each(function() {
    var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
});
```

This is of course assuming that `.load()` doesn't already show this particular behavior.